# exploiting keccak for random number generation?

Tags: solidity, keccak, randomness

Whenever a ticket will be purchased, a random number will be generated

```
function _mightWin()
        internal
    {
        address _player = msg.sender;        // players address
        uint256 _tickets = tickets_.length;  // amount of total tickets so far

        // generate random number
        uint256 _ticket = uint256(keccak256(abi.encodePacked(block.timestamp, block.difficulty, _player, _tickets))) % 289;

        // ticket has hit the winning number
        if (_ticket == 42) {
            hasWon = true;
        }
    }
```

The contract allows players to only buy 1 ticket per minute. Some genius has made a contract to play this game, where the contract buys exactly 4 tickets from 4 different addresses and wins (in a single transaction).

How is this possible? When generating the random number, timestamp and difficulty are always the same number, but the players address and the amount of tickets is different.

Comment: Do you have the full source and the transaction hash? I'd guess it is testing buying different amount of tickets. Since the chances are 1/289 then trying around a few dozens you have decent chances.